# Select data between dates

Tags: mysql, date

```
SELECT * FROM twentyfour WHERE date BETWEEN 2014-01-01 AND 2014-01-29;
```

Trying to select date from between two dates (ie. data for the month of January.

The above query says it works but nothing shows up. 'date' is also the cloumn name, should I change this to something else. Does it interfere or anything?

My DB is structured

```
id, category, date(date), name, locatoin, record_edit (datetime current_timestamp)
```

Comment: @Jens: No, date is no keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @juergend **date is a keyword**, from MySQL words `MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. ACTION, BIT, DATE, ENUM, NO, TEXT, TIME, TIMESTAMP` What you meant to say is that its not a **reserved keyword**.

Comment: 2014 - 01 - 29 = 1984

Answer (score 4):

change

```
WHERE date BETWEEN 2014-01-01 AND 2014-01-29;
```

to

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-29';
```

You need to use quote for date values.

Comment: Ah, that's why. Thank you a lot. I appreciate it.